# Emacs minimap: change color of screen zone

Tags: emacs, colors

By default the color of the area in the minimap that shows which part of the source code is being viewed on the screen right now is red. I find that very distracting. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Try placing your cursor on the point in the minimap that has the color you want to change and type:  `M-x customize-face`

Answer (score 3):

You can also configure the color in your emacs file if it's helpful.

Use the function `custom-set-faces`:

```
;; changing colors
(custom-set-faces
  '(minimap-active-region-background
    ((((background dark)) (:background "#2A2A2A222222"))
      (t (:background "#D3D3D3222222")))
    "Face for the active region in the minimap.
By default, this is only a different background color."
    :group 'minimap))
```

For more: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Faces.html